# How can I do an implode on certain fields of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: php

I have a two-dimensional array with the format shown below. How would I output only the `user_id` using `implode()` such that the end result would be `1705,1757,1832`?

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => 
    Array ( 
        [nickname] => picachu 
        [user_id] => 1705 
        [name] => picachu .jpg 
        [city_name] => pallet town
    ) 
    [1] =>
     Array (
       [nickname] => charmander 
       [user_id] => 1757  
       [name] => charmander.jpg 
       [city_name] => verivian city 
    ) 
    [2] =>
    Array ( 
       [nickname] => squaretle 
       [user_id] => 1832 
       [name] => squaretle.jpg 
       [city_name] => Celadon 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Programmers can be lazy, but not SO lazy.

Comment: You have typos there, pikachu is written with a K xD and there's an E that shouldn't be there in squartel :P

Comment: xD...not lazy just looking how to use without loop....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.5:

```
$result = join(',', array_column($data, 'user_id'));
```

5.3<=PHP<=5.4:

```
$result = join(',', array_map(function($item)
{
   return $item['user_id'];
}, $data));
```

PHP<5.3:

```
$result = join(',', array_map(create_function('$item', 'return $item["user_id"];')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$nested_array = array();
foreach($array as $a) {
    $nested_array[] = $a['user_id'];
}
$implode = implode(',',$nested_array);
```

OR

```
$implode = '';
foreach($array as $a) {
    $implode .= $a['user_id'] . ',';
}
$implode = substr($implode,-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
foreach ($array as $row)
{
  $values[] = $row['user_id'];

}
$user_id= implode(',', $values);

echo $user_id;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
implode(', ', array_map(function($k){ return $k['user_id'];}, $arr));
```